# Can Fill Factor be changed on specific tables without index rebuild?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, clustered-index, index-maintenance, fill-factor

I've been digging around without any luck.

SQL Server 2008: Is it possible to adjust the fill factor on a specific clustered index/table without having to rebuild the entire table?

For example, if it has 400 million records, can we adjust the fill factor and have SQL Server use the new fill factor on all pages that haven't already exceeded that limit (as well as new splits), and then adjust pages that are over limit during index maintenance?

Is it possible to pre-define the fill-factor that an index should be built to during the next index maintenance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not how `FILLFACTOR` works. It only applies to pages written during a `CREATE` or `REBUILD` operations. Pages are always filled as much as possible as they are created or split.

As per the MSDN documentation for [CREATE INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql):

> The FILLFACTOR setting applies only when the index is created or rebuilt.

So, even if you change the `FILLFACTOR` during a `REBUILD` (since your Clustered Index already exists), only the existing pages will make use of that value. As new pages are created, and existing pages are split, they will be filled as if the `FILLFACTOR` were set to `100`.

Or, stated another way: the rebuild operation is not your problem here as you will never get new and split pages to use a `FILLFACTOR` below `100`.

Also: No, it is not possible to "pre-define" a change to the `FILLFACTOR` value that will take affect the next time there is a `REBUILD`. It can only be specified in the `WITH` clause of a `REBUILD` operation. BUT, once you have applied the new value during a rebuild, that new value will be stored in `sys.indexes` and will be used again for subsequent rebuilds unless it is changed again by someone specifying `WITH (FILLFACTOR = x)`.

Or, again stated another way:

1. The `FILLFACTOR` value can be changed *only* when actually doing a `REBUILD` (I am not considering a `DROP` and re-`CREATE` of an Index to be a "change").
2. The `FILLFACTOR` value is used *only* by `CREATE INDEX` and `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD` (and technically also `DBCC DBREINDEX`, but that shouldn't be used as it has been [deprecated as of SQL Server 2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(v=sql.90).aspx)); `FILLFACTOR` is *not* used as rows are inserted or updated as that would defeat the purpose of having this option in the first place.

   `FILLFACTOR` reserves space on *existing* data pages so that the space *can be used* (hence reducing the chances of getting page splits); not allowing pages to fill beyond the `FILLFACTOR` value would permanently reserve that space for no purpose, effectively reducing the size of the data pages, which would actually increase, not decrease, the chances of getting page splits.

   Page split operations always move approximately 50% to the new page.

Comment: Comments [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58039/discussion-on-answer-by-srutzky-can-fill-factor-change-on-specific-tables-withou) as requested.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. `FILLFACTOR` is an option that can only be used with `REBUILD` or `CREATE`/`DROP`.
Reference [`ALTER INDEX (Transact-SQL`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql).

> ```
> <rebuild_index_option > ::=
> {
>     PAD_INDEX = { ON | OFF }
>   | FILLFACTOR = fillfactor 
>   | SORT_IN_TEMPDB = { ON | OFF }
>   | IGNORE_DUP_KEY = { ON | OFF }
>   | STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = { ON | OFF }
>   | ONLINE = { ON | OFF } 
>   | ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = { ON | OFF }
>   | ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = { ON | OFF }
>   | MAXDOP = max_degree_of_parallelism
>   | DATA_COMPRESSION = { NONE | ROW | PAGE } 
>      [ ON PARTITIONS ( { <partition_number_expression> | <range> } 
>      [ , ...n ] ) ]
> }
> <range> ::= 
> <partition_number_expression> TO <partition_number_expression>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to pre-define the fill-factor that an index should be built to during the next index maintenance?

This will be possible in MS SQL Server 2017. SQL Server 2017 is supposed to be coming with the ability to start and stop index rebuilds, which will also create the ability to execute a rebuild command with the newly specified fill factor, but then stop the rebuild, then using the new fill factor on the next scheduled index maintenance.

Comment: Dave, some comments were moved to: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58039/discussion-on-answer-by-srutzky-can-fill-factor-change-on-specific-tables-withou . Back then I said that I believe you misread the doc. I see no indication that you will be able to change FILLFACTOR, or most properties, while paused. You can only resume by issuing RESUME or reissuing the exact same REBUILD command, with _same_ properties. Unless you have tested and proven otherwise, or seen it done, I highly doubt you will be able to change the FILLFACTOR while it is paused. And you don't want it paused for too long.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. My impression is not that you can change fill factor while it is paused, but that you can change fill factor with a rebuild command, and then pause. This would make it so that your index rebuild job could also issue RESUME, this giving you the ability to adjust fill factor during the work day, but not have it actually applied until the job kicks off at night. Why do you say you don't want them paused for long?

Comment: Dave, regarding not pausing for a long time, the documentation states: "_Having a long pause for an index operation may impact the DML performance on a specific table as well as the database disk capacity since both indexes the original one and the newly created one require disk space and need to be updated during DML operations._". I am also guessing that certain operations, such as anything requiring a Schema-Lock, will be block, but I'm not sure about that as I haven't tested it.

Comment: Regarding the plan to start the rebuild with a different `FILLFACTOR`, I suppose that would work _IF_ your index rebuild job _knew_ to issue a `RESUME` rather than a `REBUILD`, but so far I am not sure how one would determine if an operation is paused.

Comment: Good point. I assumed that the resume command would resume all paused rebuild operations, which is not a great assumption in hind sight. Speaking to space consumption and impact on DML, as long as you pause it in the same batch that you start it, it seems possible that there would be no DML issues.

Comment: Dave, DML operations can come from anywhere. The moment you start a REBUILD operation that uses `ONLINE = ON` (which is a requirement for being pausable), the system makes a copy of the index so that it can rearrange it while the table is still available. During that time, the space is duplicated (or more possibly as there is transaction space) and the DML operations need to happen to both indexes.

Comment: Is any of that assumption? The indexes I'm thinking of are going to take a while to make a copy of. If you're right, it may mean you couldn't pause until that was complete...? Or if you can pause before the copy is made, it wouldn't effect DML

Comment: Dave, I don't know the specifics about the timing of that, but I do know that the documentation states both: "_Resumable indexes not supported with All keyword._" and "_In case the base table contains LOB column(s) resumable clustered index rebuild requires a Sch-M lock in the beginning of this operation_". So, you need to check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-index-resumable-operations to see if it is paused and issue a specific `RESUME`, and a clustered index with LOB columns will be dangerous for holding a Schema lock for such a long time.

Answer (score -1):

No. The moment you change the fill factor, it will rebuild the table. There is no selective pages that you can change the fill factor to.